# Semantic Logging Analyzer exception number of WriteEvent arguments and event parameters are different

Tags: c#, enterprise-library-5, semantic-logging

This fragment makes the Semantic Log Analyzer throw **"The number of WriteEvent arguments and event parameters are different in event name 'HandlingCommand'."**

```
[NonEvent]
public void HandlingCommand(Command command)
{
    if (this.IsEnabled())
    {
        this.HandlingCommand(command.Id.ToString(), command.Agent.AgentId.ToString());
    }
}

[Event(1101,
    Level = EventLevel.Informational,
    Keywords = Keywords.Agent)]
private void HandlingCommand(string commandId, string agentId)
{
    this.WriteEvent(1101, commandId, agentId);
}
```

The only way to resolve the analyzer error is to have two WriteEvent parameters (event id and commandId for example) and one event argument (commandId for example). If I try with any combination with more than one  parameter/argument the above mentioned exception is thrown. The exception is thrown on any event with more than one parameter/argument not just the supplied example.

I have used these samples as a starting point https://github.com/mspnp/semantic-logging/tree/master/quickstarts.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error, having no success. Could you add the remaining code to the snippet?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error and couldn't figure it out. Eventually I got the EventSourceAnalyzer code, compiled and debugged.

What I found was that my `WriteEvent` was actually writing the following:
 **EventSourceException while processing event "MethodName": No Free Buffers available from the operating system (e.g. event rate too fast).**

in the EventSourceAnalyzer class there is this line:
`if (eventParameters.Length != this.EventData.Payload.Count)`
`throw mismatch exception`

Now, because my `WriteEvent` was actually passing in 3 params, the fact that the `WriteEvent` was in essence throwing an error caused the `EventSourceAnalyzer` to incorrectly interpret it as a mismatch.